# Simple way of moving options between two drop-down lists?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to develop a simple way to move options from one drop-down list to another drop-down list using JavaScript or JQuery. However EVERY example I find on the internet is really old or just plain doesn't work (my own knowledge is a bit limited).

Can anyone help me develop a simple way of moving options between drop-down lists?

Here's the HTML I have:

```
<select name="sourceSelect" id="sourceSelect" size="3"  onclick="">
  <option value="example1">Example1</option>
  <option value="example2">Example2</option>
  <option value="example3">Example3</option>
</select>


<input type="submit" name="forward" id="forward" value="Forward" onclick=""/>

<input type="submit" name="back" id="back" value="Back" onclick=""/>


<select name="destinationSelect" id="destinationSelect" multiple="multiple" size="3" onclick="">
  <!--EMPTY DROP-DOWN LIST-->
</select>
```

I think the names of the drop-down lists might need to be changed to sourceSelect[] if arrays are used? Also I've added empty onclick's but I'm not sure if it is necessary to do it that way?

Comment: You want to *cut/paste* or *copy/paste*? What event should be handled to launch the option-moving process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/RsgR3/10/) is a working solution that uses jQuery:

```
function cutAndPaste(from, to) {
    $(to).append(function() {
        return $(from + " option:selected").each(function() {
            this.outerHTML;
        }).remove();
    });
}

$("#forward").off("click").on("click", function() {
    cutAndPaste("#sourceSelect", "#destinationSelect");
});

$("#backward").off("click").on("click", function() {
    cutAndPaste("#destinationSelect", "#sourceSelect");
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks, that works great. However do you have any idea how you get the form to submit ALL the options in destinationSelect when the whole form is submitted?

Comment: @AzzyDude Use brackets at the end of the name of the `select`, for example `<select name="destinationSelect[]" ... />`.

Comment: @AzzyDude Using brackets, you'll get (server-side) an *array* containing all the values of the selected options of the `select`.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, at its simplest the code for your forward button could be:

```
$('#forward').on('click',function(){

    var $selected = $('option:selected','#sourceSelect');
    $selected.each(function(i,e){
        $('#destinationSelect').append(
            $('<option />').val(e.value).html(e.innerHTML)
        );
    });
    $selected.remove();
});
```

And your back button:

```
$('#back').on('click',function(){

    var $selected = $('option:selected','#destinationSelect');
    $selected.each(function(i,e){
        $('#sourceSelect').append(
            $('<option />').val(e.value).html(e.innerHTML)
        );
    });
    $selected.remove();
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/y6B8Q/

You can then take this as far as you like, making your own jquery plugin if you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

```
var content_option = $('#sourceSelect option[value="example1"]').contents();
$('#sourceSelect option[value="example1"]').remove();
$('#destinationSelect').append('<option value="example1">'+content_option+'</option>');
```

Answer (score 0):

`Javascript` solution could be iterating over the options of `source` select and adding it to `destination` as below

```
    for (i=0;i<sourceSelect.length;i++)
    {
      var newOption = document.createElement('<option value="'+sourceSelect.options[i].text+'">');
      destinationSelect.options.add(newOption);
    }
```

Also if you want to `clear` the source select then add following

```
sourceSelect.innerHTML = ''
```